# Python:Moving through linked list 'next'

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm working through Cracking the Coding Interview 6th ed and am unsure of their definition of 'next'

Their code defining "Linked List" can be found [here](https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition-Python/blob/master/Chapter%202/LinkedList.py). I'm trying out the second exercise, which is to find the kth from the end element of a random linked list.

My code:

```
from LinkedList import LinkedList

def kth_to_last(ll, k):
    num_seen = 0
    length_list = count_length(ll)

    val = ll.head

    # ISSUE IS HERE
    while val.next != None:
        print 'hi'
        val.next = val.next.next

    """
    while num_seen < (length_list - k):
        val = val.next
        num_seen += 1
    """
    return val.next


# Counts length of LL
def count_length(ll):
    val = ll.head
    count = 1
    while val.next != None:
        count += 1
        val.next = val.next.next
    return count


ll = LinkedList()
ll.generate(10, 0, 99)
print(ll)
kth_to_last(ll, 3)
```

It's counting through the list just fine, but for the first definition, I can't get it to move through the linked list (it won't print 'hi' at all).

I plan to do something like I have commented out (they also have 'tail' defined so I might try that out), but I'm confused why I can move through the list just fine within 'count_length,' but then I can't seem to move through it within 'kth_to_last'?

Edit: To clarify, if I print val.next within 'kth_to_last' it has a value of 'None'

Edit2:

If I comment out the "count_length," the next proceeds just fine. Could someone explain to me why calling this function alters next. Has it stuck me at the end of the list?

My code:

```
def kth_to_last(ll, k):
    """
    num_seen = 0
    length_list = count_length(ll)
    """

    # Start at head
    val = ll.head
    while val.next != None:
        print val.next
        val = val.next
```

This prints the list just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `val = val.next` instead of `val.next = val.next.next`.  The way you're doing it, the list will be truncated to a single element when you call `count_length`.  Because you do `count_length` at the top of `kth_to_last`, by the time you get around to walking your list (where your `'hi'` is), the list has already been reduced to a single node.

Remember, a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is a structure where each node's `next` property is a pointer to the next node.  Your code is modifying the value of `next`, which is changing the structure of your linked list.

When you process a linked list (in `count_length`, or in `kth_to_last`), what you want to do is point yourself at each node in turn.  You're not trying to modify the nodes themselves, so you won't assign to their `value` or `next` attributes.  The way to do this is to change what your pointer (`val`) is pointing at, and the thing that you want it to point at next is the next node along.  Therefore:

```
val = ll.head
while val is not None:
    # do something with val here
    val = val.next
```

Comment: Thank you @wildwilhelm, that makes sense, I will fix that.

Comment: So the issue appears to be with my calling of "count_length" because if I comment it out then val_next is fine. Why does counting the length alter the ll?

Comment: Thank you @wildwilhelm, I just saw your full comment--that makes complete sense. Thank you!